# Is there any maven plugin that sends HTTP requests and validates results?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to find a maven plugin that sends a HTTP request to the URL specified, parses response against some regular expression, and fails build if the matching fails. Do you know any?

Comment: is there any reason you don't want to do this in a unit test?

Comment: I want to do it **after** deployment. I want to HTTP-ping the application in the application server, to be sure it is successfully deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use Groovy Maven plugin, which is the easiest solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the [jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) plugin:

http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin

here's a little tutorial on how to get it running...
http://www.ronniealleva.org/index.php/maven-jmeter-plugin/